# How can I get IE 11 to show my .ts files?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, javascript-debugger

I got IS 11 installed today (F12 in it rocks!) and at first it was displaying my .ts files in the debugger. But now it's displaying the .js files. Is there something I need to set?

I use WebStorm to build my .ts files and it creates the map file. I do get the .ts files in Chrome (most of the time).

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

See this page and try to toggle the source map icon: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255007(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any way to have it default to mapping being on? At present for half my files it defaults to showing the .ts file, for the other half I have to click it each time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

F12 will turn off source maps for a given source map if it finds an error in the map file or if it can't find the sources it refers to. By default those errors are silent you can show them by adding the registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\F12]
"DebuggerShowSourceMapErrors"="True"
```

That's assuming an error caused it to be disabled. As Dave mentioned the feature can also be disabled but F12 should remember when it's disabled/enabled on a per file basis (the toggle is per file not global).

Comment: Should be, but it apparently does not work that way on my system. It randomly brings up files, some showing the .ts, some the .js. I can always click the button to get to .ts mode, but it's annoying to have to do so.